# Promise returns {} instead of ImageData (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Trying to use this code in TypeScript:

```
convertURIToImageData(URI) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (URI == null) { return reject(); }
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const image = new Image();
      image.addEventListener('load', () => {
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        resolve(imageData);
      }, false);
      image.src = URI;
    });}
```

to return ImageData from the Promise but all I'm getting is {}

Using it like this:

```
this.convertURIToImageData('url').then((img) => {
  // do stuff with ImageData
})
```

Getting:

```
 Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ImageData'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ImageData': data, height, width
```

Comment: how are you determining that its just `{}`?

Comment: If your intent is to get a `data:image` type return, you should use `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` with your desired image MIME type.

Comment: It's hard to tell because you haven't actually added the crucial bit of code, but I'd imagine this is a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The `{}` is the return type that TypeScript reports, or the actual value in runtime?

Comment: It's actually in Angular build/serve, getting:
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ImageData'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ImageData': data, height, width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is currently TypeScript's fallback type. If TypeScript cannot infer what type is being returned from a function, it will automatically infer `{}`. TypeScript, is not able to infer the type of `img` in the context you're using it, so it infers `{}` and fails to compile.

You can confirm this is happening if you have TypeScript integrated into your code editor by simply hovering over the function, you will see the return type is `Promise<{}>`. You can easily fix this by annotating the functions return type:

```
convertURIToImageData(URI): Promise<ImageData> {
```

Now the return type is correctly shown as `Promise<ImageData>` and your code should compile.

Comment: But why can it not infer the type? Seems like it should work.

Comment: I agree it's odd, I think it has something to do with using `resolve` and `reject` as opposed to marking the function `async`. Seems like `resolve` is typed to return `{}` instead of using some generic for whatever reason